# Replacing a Webpage (Auto Generated), without Causing Temporary a "Page Not Found" Error

Tags: automation

Imagine this scenario:

You have a website, with only 1 page, the page is an .HTML file.
This page is Auto Generated every 10 minutes by some program that you wrote.
This program is running in the background.
(this program is a different process, and is not a web-application)

Every 10 mins, the program generates a new version of the page,
and it then needs to **replace** the old page with the new one that it had just created.

Let's assume our HTML webpage is called `Page.html`.

So to replace it, the program can do this:
1) Create the updated version of the page, with a file name `Page_New.html`
2) Delete the older `Page.html` file
3) Rename `Page_New.html` to `Page.html`

This will indeed replace the older file with the new one,
but the only problem is that for a short time, there will not be any file found, for requests for that page..
So users will receive a `Page not Found` message, if they visit the website exactly when the pages are being switched.

My question:
Is there a way to tell a Web Server that I am replacing a file,
and so every request to that file (URL) while it's being replaced, should be **delayed**, and not returned with a `Page not Found` message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS file system uses file locks and triggers to resolve these issues. For example, you issue a copy command to copy page_new.html to page.html, the file system locks page.html, overwrites page.html with page_new.html, then releases the lock on page.html. For any read request for page.html issued to the file system while the file is locked, a trigger is issued and the request is put on hold. When the lock is released on page.html the trigger is tripped and the read request is processed. This happens so fast that it is transparent. Using this scenario no "page of found" will happen because at no time does the file not exist. However, if you delete page.html before the copy, a "page not found" error can happen. It is far superior to copy over a file and not delete it.

Comment: Thank you closetnoc for your answer.  OK, so your solution is to simply use the `Copy command`, overwriting the old file, instead of deleting it first. This solution is based on a behavior in which the OS locks the file (for **both** Read and Write) before starting to overwrite it, and until the overwriting is complete. Now the only question left is whether every OS behaves like that, meaning the file is locked for both Read and Write, and not just for Write.. (or else, the webserver can serve an interim file, with mixed content from the old and new versions of it). Is it correct for all OSes?

Comment: @spaceman Good question! There are actually several locks, read, write, read/write known as exclusive, etc. There are more locks, but this is enough. Since a copy operation is a "file destruct" operation, an exclusive lock is required to prevent all accesses until the operation is complete. Most languages allow for copy operations that are nothing more than access to certain shell operations. At the very end of your code you can simply close your temp file and do a copy over your live web page. I did this for years and years exactly this way. Worked like a champ! Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- I am a retired system internals engineer. I wrote OS components, device drivers, network protocol stacks, etc. starting with Digital Equipment Corporation (DEC), and others ending as a consultant. Just so you know. You should be okay.

Comment: Great. I will use this solution. Thank you, and much appreciation for a simple solution.. :)